# I can’t translate myself

Tags: memo

a few hours ago, I made a currency exchange for stellar, but I did not indicate memo, the screenshot of the exchange is shown below, but the funds never came not a wallet.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to contact the exchange with these transaction details. They are the one's holding your funds and will be the only ones who can help you.